# Filter PHP's $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Tags: php, security

I need to filter the unreliable $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] varialbe. Is this a good approach:

```
function filterPhpSelf($str) 
{
    $phpself = basename(__FILE__);
    $str = substr($str, 0, strpos($str,$phpself)) . $phpself;
    return $unsafeStr;
}
```

where $str is $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?

Comment: And what do you want to filter out?

Answer (score 2):

1) Your code will raise an error if run.

2) `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is not unsafe. Unsafe use of it is unsafe.

Comment: You're right Kris .. I misread that, it seems. Of course that begs the question as to what's unreliable about it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will do. Though you will want to change:

```
return $unsafeStr;
```

to

```
return $str;
```